# source code for sin() in FORTRAN

Tags: function, fortran, implementation, trigonometry

I want to know how the build-in function sin() is implemented in FORTRAN, because I try to write functions that can receive both scalars and array as its input variable, the effect of which can be found in sin(), that sin(0) returns 0 and sin(a), where array a=(/0,3.14...), returns an array (0,0).
   
I hope all mathematical functions I am gonna write can have this kind of flexibility and advantage. Someone could do me a favor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an [`elemental` function](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/elemental)

Comment: thanks a lot ! it is really useful for defining mathematical functions